# Dropwizard JDBI autogenerated value on inserts

Tags: java, rest, dropwizard, jdbi

I am using Dropwizard with JDBI and would like the insert statement to automatically generate a key.

My table 'dataset' has the form

```
SELECT * FROM dataset ;
id          xaxis                yaxis            
----------  -------------------  -----------------
1           230,234,23,423,4234  32,34,234,23,4234
```

for my DAO I added the annotations

```
  @GetGeneratedKeys
  @SqlUpdate("INSERT INTO DATASET (XAXIS, YAXIS) VALUES (:xaxis,:yaxis)")
  long insert(@Bind("xaxis") String xaxis, @Bind("yaxis") String yaxis);
```

I overwrite the method as

```
  @Override
  public long insert(Dataset dataset) {
    return datasetJBDIDao.insert(dataset.getXaxis(), dataset.getYaxis());
  }
```

As resource I run

```
  @POST
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public Response insertDataset(Dataset dataset) {
    long id = datasetDao.insert(dataset);
    Dataset toReturn = new Dataset(id, dataset.getXaxis(), dataset.getYaxis());
    return Response.ok(toReturn).build();
  }
```

However Each time I run the Post request with a body the data is added but without the id value

```
SELECT * FROM dataset ;
id          xaxis                yaxis            
----------  -------------------  -----------------
1           230,234,23,423,4234  32,34,234,23,4234
            1,2,3,4,5            1,3,4,6,7
```

Does anybody know how to solve this issue

Comment: You can make the datatype of id SERIAL while creating the table, or read value from a sequence.

Comment: How is the `id` column defined? Does the type autogenerate values? JDBI will not create them for you.

Comment: is id column auto generated by database /

Comment: Thank you guys. I saw that initialed the the table wrongly.